# emgu FindContours fails in debug build

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, emgucv

I have some Emgu code that was working in both debug and release builds.  Somewhere along the way, it quit working, but I was deep into adding something else so I didn't pursue it at the time.

When I did finally getting around to trying to fix it, I find that a release build works, but not a debug build.  Between the time it was working, and not, I did not change any references or referenced DLLs. I spent some time investigating that anyhow as I had read somewhere that open CV has some trouble debug vs release somewhere, but never found anything.

I just applied the last version of Emgu, and the same problem exists;  works perfect in release, not at all in debug.

The relevant code snippet is;

```
 var filteredFrame =
            channels[0].SmoothGaussian(VisionData.SmoothGaussians)
                .Erode(VisionData.Erodes)
                .Dilate(VisionData.Dialates);

        using (MemStorage stor = new MemStorage())
            for (
                Contour<System.Drawing.Point> contour =
                    filteredFrame.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
                        Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, stor);
                contour != null;
                contour = contour.HNext)
                if ((contour.Area > (VisionData.ContourMinArea * VisionData.ContourMinArea))
                    && (contour.Area < (VisionData.ContourMaxArea * VisionData.ContourMaxArea)))
                    CurrentFrame.Draw(contour.GetMinAreaRect(), RectBrush, 2);

        d.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            DataModel.CameraImageSource = Emgu.CV.WPF.BitmapSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(CurrentFrame);
            DataModel.FilteredImageSource = Emgu.CV.WPF.BitmapSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(filteredFrame);                                
        });
```

The input filtered frame(image) looks identical in both debug and release.